# For loop behaviour in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to use a `for` loop and an `if` statement in my `R` code, as below.

It produces a density plot, and I am then trying to add a vertical line to the density which is coloured by species.

When I `print(organism)` within the `for` loop it prints the Species column 4 times, why does it not print it out once? So therefore is it cycling 4 times through my data?

The code manages to add some red lines to the density plot, but why is it not adding the remaining coloured lines for the other species?

```
dat <- structure(list(pdb = structure(1:13, .Label = c("1akk.pdb", "1fi7.pdb", 
"1fi9.pdb", "1giw.pdb", "1hrc.pdb", "1i5t.pdb", "1j3s0.10.pdb", 
"1j3s0.11.pdb", "1j3s0.12.pdb", "1j3s0.13.pdb", "1j3s0.14.pdb", 
"2aiu.pdb", "2b4z.pdb"), class = "factor"), PA = c(1128, 1143, 
1119, 1130, 1055, 1112, 1120, 1121, 1135, 1102, 1121, 1037, 1179
), EHSS = c(1424, 1439, 1404, 1423, 1318, 1403, 1412, 1415, 1432, 
1391, 1413, 1299, 1441), Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("BOSTAURUS", 
"EQUUSCABALLUS", "HOMOSAPIENS", "MUSMUSCULUS"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("pdb", 
"PA", "EHSS", "Species"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

den.PA <- density(dat$PA)
plot(den.PA)

for (i in 1:length(dat)){
    lineat = dat$PA[i]
    organism = dat$Species[i]
    lineheight <- den.PA$y[which.min(abs(den.PA$x - lineat))]
    print (organism)
    if (organism == 'EQUUSCABALLUS'){
        col = 'red'
    }
    if (organism == 'HOMOSAPIENS'){
        col = 'blue'
    }
    if (organism == 'MUSMUSCULUS'){
        col = 'green'
    }
    if (organism == 'BOSTAURUS'){
        col = 'purple'
    }
    lines(c(lineat, lineat), c(0, lineheight), col = col)
}
```

Comment: your `read.table()` statement doesn't produce a useable object for me. If you have a normal-seeming object called `dat`, how about you copy and paste the console output from `dput(dat)` for us?

Comment: the dput(dat) output is above

Comment: and your loop only does 1:4, since a `data.frame` is a `list`, and the `length()` of a `data.frame` is its number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking your `dat` from `dput()`, you can change your code to iterate over the rows, and first convert the the `PA` to class `character` before extracting the element. That way you'll get 13 lines:

```
    den.PA <- density(dat$PA)
    plot(den.PA)

    for (i in 1:nrow(dat)){
        lineat <- dat$PA[i]
        organism <- as.character(dat$Species)[i]
        lineheight <- den.PA$y[which.min(abs(den.PA$x - lineat))]
        print (organism)
        if (organism == 'EQUUSCABALLUS'){
            col <- 'red'
        }
        if (organism == 'HOMOSAPIENS'){
            col <- 'blue'
        }
        if (organism == 'MUSMUSCULUS'){
            col <- 'green'
        }
        if (organism == 'BOSTAURUS'){
            col <- 'purple'
        }
        segments(lineat,0,lineat,lineheight,col=col)
    }
```

[image]

also, I changed `lines()` to `segments()`, since you just have 2 points. That doesn't make much difference however. I also changed declarations using `=` to `<-`, which hurts the eyes of most R users less.

Answer (score 2):

For a more "R-ish" solution, try using `match`, `approx`, and `points` with the histogram type.

```
den.PA <- density(dat$PA)
cols <- data.frame(Species=c('EQUUSCABALLUS', 'HOMOSAPIENS', 'MUSMUSCULUS', 'BOSTAURUS'),
                   col=c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
plot(den.PA)
points(approx(den.PA$x, den.PA$y, dat$PA), type="h", 
       col=cols$col[match(dat$Species, cols$Species)])
```

Comment: agreed, I tried to cram it into a single call to `segments()` using a bunch of nested `ifelse()` statements and gave up. +1 for R-ness

Answer (score 1):

Side answer:  you'll get smoother code if you replace all the `if` with a single `switch` construction.

From the help page:

```
 centre <- function(x, type) {
     + switch(type,
     +        mean = mean(x),
     +        median = median(x),
     +        trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
     + }
```

One of the nice things here is that you can put as much as you want on the right-hand side of any case.  e.g. in the example I posted, you could do:
 
              `+     mean = {cat"this is the mean"; y=mean(x)*sin(z);plot(z,y)}`

as a silly example.